# jQuery remove() is not working

Tags: jquery, xml, ajax

Here is source:

```
function updateMsg() {
    $.post("AjaxChatServer.jsp",{ time: timestamp }, function(xml) {
        alert("1");
        $("#loading").remove();
        addMessages(xml);
    });
    setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
}
```

that `alert` function is not working, but outside of `function(xml)`, `alert` is working.
Does jQuery source has a problem?

Comment: it means u are not getting any ajax response. check. `AjaxChatServer.jsp`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your success callback is not triggering, it is most likely because the request was unsuccessful. See the [.post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) documentation. I would suggest using the more full-featured [.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) to have more control over the situation.

```
function updateMsg() {
    // You must define timestamp
    var timestamp = $.now();
    $.ajax({
        url: "AjaxChatServer.jsp",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            time: timestamp
        },
        success: function (xml, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $("#loading").remove();
            addMessages(xml);
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            // Handle error
            alert(textStatus);
        }
    });
}

setTimeout(updateMsg, 4000);
```

Comment: +1 for surfacing `$.now()` for me :)

Answer (score 3):

Change:

```
setTimeout('updateMsg()', 4000);
```

to:

```
setTimeout(updateMsg, 4000);
```

Also note that in the posted code, `timestamp` is `undefined` and you should put `setTimeout` outside of the function's scope.

Comment: It's good advice, but `'updateMsg()'` will work just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you maybe have problem with the ajax - error somewhere.
try to add `.error` and `.success` in the end of the post function to see the error.

> > ```
> > function updateMsg() {
> >
> > $.post("AjaxChatServer.jsp",{ time: timestamp }, function(xml) {
> >   alert("1");
> >   $("#loading").remove();
> >
> >  addMessages(xml);
> > })  .error(function(){
> >         alert("error");
> >      })  .success (function(){
> >         alert("error");
> >      );
> > ```

Answer (score 0):

Your variable "timestamp" is declared?

Try :

```
function updateMsg() {
    var date = new Date(), timestamp = date.getTime();

    $.post("AjaxChatServer.jsp",{ time: timestamp }, function(xml) {
       alert("1");
       $("#loading").remove();

       addMessages(xml);
    });
}
```